# How to package a project which uses a fork of Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, packaging

I am building a project which requires a forked version of Symfony with [features that are not yet merged](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/48272). The forked version of Symfony is hosted on a git server so I tried depending on `symfony/symfony` using this in *composer.json*:

```json
{
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "vcs",
      "url": "https://github.com/vincentchalamon/symfony.git"
    }
  ],
  "require": {
    "symfony/symfony": "dev-feat/oidc-access-token-handler"
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

However, my project also requires other Symfony bundles that are not in the `symfony/symfony` package. Moreover, using `symfony/symfony` is deprecated in favor of using smaller bundles from Symfony. Using `symfony/symfony` also causes compatibility issues with other bundles.

I was able to make this project work anyways using the `php link` utility [as documented in the docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/contributing/code/pull_requests.html#use-your-branch-in-an-existing-project). However, this technique is not really suitable for distribution.

How can I package my application to use a forked version of Symfony? Ideally, I'd like to only tweak the *composer.json*.

Comment: I suggest that do not use fork of symfony. You can easily install all symfony packages in your project. And also you can overwrite modules of symfony if you want in your project.

Comment: Why not put the code you need into your package?

Comment: @BhavinNakrani How would I overwrite modules of Symfony? The [changes I need](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/48272/files) have changes both in `Bundle/SecurityBundle` and in `Component/Security`.

Comment: Oh, you made lot of changes in core component. Can you do in your personal bundle and install it? ex: you can copy code of bundle https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/security-bundle and add your changes and publish in packagist and install in composer.

Comment: @BhavinNakrani Actually, these changes are not from me. These are proposed changes from an _API Platform_ contributor to support OpenID Connect. I considered integrating these changes into a fork of `Bundle/SecurityBundle`. I am however not sure what to do with `Component/Security` changes. There seems to be no "core" bundle.

Comment: _"However, this technique is not really suitable for distribution."_ - why is that? how do you distribute?

Comment: @hakre Requiring unusual extra steps compared to `composer i` is a hassle IMHO.

Comment: Maybe it's better to wait for an official release of that feature, or use any other package that already provides the required feature? I would never install any package that replaces the "original" Symfony packages with any forked version

Comment: If that is the case, then what @NicoHaase suggests otherwise only asking for problems. Just postpone the release until the feature is available if automation doesn't work for you.